# Бот никого не видит кроме себя

Tags: discord, discord.py

Моя проблема такова: бот в цикле for выводит только себя самого, а других не выводит, пробовал через print выводить. Ошибок никаких вообще нету, просто бот не видит.

```
async def on_ready():
    print("[",time.strftime("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S"),"] Бот загружен.")

    guild = client.get_guild(айди гильдии)
    for member in guild.members:
        mname = member.name
        mdisc = member.discriminator
        print(mname + mdisc)
```

Answer (score 0):

В профиле вашего бота отключен Intent "SERVER MEMBERS INTENT".
Чтобы его включить,

1. Перейдите в профиль вашего бота, в [портале разработчиков](https://discord.com/developers/applications).

2. Откройте вкладку "Bot".
3. Пролистайте ниже, до "Privileged Gateway Intents".
4. Включите пункт "SERVER MEMBERS INTENT".